# Why does MS Visual Studio #include <stdio.h> in stdafx.h by default?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, stdafx.h

MS Visual Studio 2017, new Windows Console Application project from VisualC++ category. The default `stdafx.h` header includes the following lines:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
```

And below them:

```
// TODO: reference additional headers your program requires here
```

Because this comment is put below, not above `#include <stdio.h>`, I am inclined to believe that `stdio.h` is included by default not as a convenience for the user who would probably `#include` it anyway, but is for some reason required? The fact that `stdio.h` is included rather than `cstdio` only seems to support this interpretation?

AM I right? Can I safely remove `#include <stdio.h>`? I'm asking because the very first line in my `main` function reads:

```
std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
```

Which is obviously incorrect if facilities from `stdio` are being used anyway, as this header being included would suggest.

1) Can I safely remove the line that says `#include <stdio.h>` from `stdafx.h`?

2) Can I safely call `std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false)`?

3) Is the fact that `tchar.h` is also included by default relevant here?

Comment: It is just a template file to help starting new project. Fix it as your convenience. Quality of that template is debatable.

Comment: It's probably because nobody has updated that template in decades... ``TCHAR`` is pretty old-school as well since modern apps should just use Unicode--the last time ANSI really mattered was Windows 95. Most people, however, probably use ``printf`` or ``wprintf`` in their console app.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can remove it.

You can even name your precompiled header not stdafx.h, or disable percompiled header at all.

It is just convenience and example to start with.

Answer (score 0):

Its up to you if you want to use it, however before removing it read on this [MSDN about precompiled Header Files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h552b3ca.aspx)

Hope this helps!